# jstree is not loading icons in MVC5 from css url

Tags: css, angularjs, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5, jstree

I'm trying to use jsTree in AngularJS powered MVC5 school project. To use jsTree in angular app I'm using [this directive](http://jstree-directive.herokuapp.com/#/basic).

From what I can observe everthing working ok:
 - jstree loads correctly data and structure, and fires all events
 - jstree loads CSS style (if i change for instance margin in css, it's reflected to jstree, if remove css reference it rendered as ordinary HTML UL)

However it looks like, that rest of layout doesnt work:
 - no background change, when i move cursor over node
 - no conectors, no node images, no arrows

From what i was able to find it looks like that css is not using images referenced in it:

```
background-image: url("data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhCwAHAIAAACgoKP///yH5BAEAAAEALAAAAAALAAcAAAIORI4JlrqN1oMSnmmZDQUAOw==");

background-image: url("32px.png");

background-image: url("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABgAAAACAQMAAAB49I5GAAAABlBMVEUAAAAdHRvEkCwcAAAAAXRSTlMAQObYZgAAAAxJREFUCNdjAAMOBgAAGAAJMwQHdQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==");
```

So I tried to use:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/jstree").Include(
                "~/Content/jstree/style.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransform()));
```

Css with images is placed in same folder:

[image: content/jstree]

But that also did not worked. Any ideas? Sugestions?

Rest of the code:

```js
angular.module('JosefinaApp', ['ui.layout', 'JosefinaApp.controllers', 'jsTree.directive']);

angular.module('JosefinaApp.controllers', [])
    .controller('TreeViewController', ['$scope', '$location', '$http', function ($scope, $location, $http) {
        $location.path('/home');
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/api/project/gettasks/1',
        }).
        success(function (data) {
            $scope.treeModel = data;
        }).
        error(function () {
            $scope.test = "Error";
        });

        $scope.treeViewNodeSelected = function (e, data) {
            console.log(data.node.id);
           
        };
    }])
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title ng-bind="models.helloAngular"></title>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/plugins/jquery.validate.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/plugins/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.min.js")" type="text/javascript"> </script>
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/all.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Styles.Render("~/jqueryUI")
    @Styles.Render("~/uiLayout")
    @Styles.Render("~/jstree")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryUI")
    
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/angular.js")" type="text/javascript"> </script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/angular-ui-router.js")" type="text/javascript"> </script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/angular-resource.js")" type="text/javascript"> </script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/angular-ui/ui-layout.js")" type="text/javascript"> </script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jstree/jstree.js")" type="text/javascript"> </script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jstree/jsTree.directive.js")" type="text/javascript"> </script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/JosefinaApp.js")" type="text/javascript"> </script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Controllers/LandingPageController.js")" type="text/javascript"> </script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Controllers/TreeViewController.js")" type="text/javascript"> </script>
</head>
<body>



    <div ng-app="JosefinaApp">

        <div ng-controller="TreeViewController">

            <js-tree theme="default" tree-events="select_node:treeViewNodeSelected" tree-data="scope" tree-model="treeModel">
            </js-tree>
        </div>

    </div>   

    @RenderBody()

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So far I tried to change 'background-image: url("32px.png");' to 'background-image: url("content/jstree/32px.png");' with combination of not using bundle and referencing css directly... Also when I try to get image with: <img src="@Url.Content("~/content/jstree/32px.png")"/> it works ok... :( aaaah this is killing me

Comment: Also when try to use it without angular from html same problem....

Answer (score 1):

Browser stored images, internet explorer was caching empty images and showing them instead of geting them from server.

... kill me please